# Div not hidding with tailwind class

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Im having a problem trying to hide some div with tailwinds

I have two divs but both are showing in desktop and mobile

Div 1: has to show on desktop and hide on mobile.

```
<div class="hidden md:block" style="margin-bottom":5px></div>
```

Div 2: hast to show on mobile and hide on desktop:

```
<div class="hidden lg:block" style="margin-bottom":5px></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To apply a visibility utility only at a specific breakpoint, add a `{screen}`: prefix to the existing class name. For example, adding the class `md:invisible` to an element would apply the invisible utility at medium screen sizes and above.
>
> https://tailwindcss.com/docs/visibility#responsive

## 1

This is hidden on mobile but visible on desktop.

```
<div class="invisible md:visible"></div>
```

## 2

This is visible on mobile but hidden on desktop.

```
<div class="visible md:invisible ..."></div>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.15/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="invisible md:visible">
  Visible on desktop
</div>


<div class="visible md:invisible">
  Visible on mobile
</div>
```

---

You may use `lg` instead of `md`.

Comment: I reviewed this and is not working, it looks like it works because google was only displaying one add and letting the other empty. But still both divs appear

Comment: @SEVENELEVEN you may use an older version of tailwinds.  Run the code snippe and change the browser size, see if it works.